# How to require a file in Wordpress plugin folder?

Tags: wordpress, include, themes

I have Stripe plugin installed at wp-content/plugins/stripe/. I have a page named "Payment.php" in theme/fifthteen/Payment.php. Now I want to include the file wp-content/plugins/stripe/Stripe.php in my Payment.php. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use
   plugins_url( $path, $plugin );

$path will hold path of the file in  your plugin

```
$path = 'stripe.php';
```

$plugin holds the name of your plugin

```
$plugin='stripe' ;

include plugins_url($path,$plugin) ;
```

Comment: So is it will be
require  plugins_url('lib/Stripe.php','wp-full-stripe');
which:
lib/Stripe.php is the path of the file in my plugin, and,
wp-full-stripe is the plugin name (folder name in wp-content/plugins) ?

Comment: I got a fatal error:
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/lib/Stripe.php' (include_path='.;D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentyfifteen\paytest.php on line  259 (->the line of require statement above)

Comment: The error is showing that plugin folder is not included in path. Is your plugin visible in admin panel.Is it registered ??

Comment: To register you need to put required comments in your plugins main file.

Comment: I replaced the "require" with "include" and it worked too. Thankyou so much :)

Comment: If an answer works for you. Then accept the answers so that other users know what solved your problem. In this way we can be more constructive for the community. Cheers